# Branding a third party module of maven base Netbeans module

Tags: maven, netbeans-8, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I have a Maven base Netbeans application which uses a third party module. How can I change icons or strings of that module in my branding module?

I see that in branding module one can change branding of Netbeans platform`s modules. Is there similar way for other modules?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe branding separates between platform JARs or 3rd party JARs so I don't see why it wouldn't work.

The 3rd party module would have to be branding aware, ie. use [ImageUtilities.loadImage(String, true)](http://bits.netbeans.org/7.1/javadoc/org-openide-util/org/openide/util/ImageUtilities.html#loadImage(java.lang.String,%20boolean))